# How to force to set Pipelines' status to failed

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Copy Data.
When there is some data error. I would export them to a blob.
But in this case, the Pipelines's status is still Succeeded. I want to set it to false. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When there is some data error.

It depends on what error you mentioned here.

1.If you mean it's common incompatibility or mismatch error, ADF supports built-in feature named [Fault tolerance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#supported-scenarios) in Copy Activity which supports below 3 scenarios:

- Incompatibility between the source data type and the sink native
  type.
- Mismatch in the number of columns between the source and the sink.
- Primary key violation when writing to SQL Server/Azure SQL
  Database/Azure Cosmos DB.

If you configure to log the incompatible rows, you can find the log file at this path: `https://[your-blob-account].blob.core.windows.net/[path-if-configured]/[copy-activity-run-id]/[auto-generated-GUID].csv`.

If you want to abort the job as soon as any error occurs,you could set as below:

[image]

Please see this case: [Fault tolerance and log the incompatible rows in Azure Blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088308/fault-tolerance-and-log-the-incompatible-rows-in-azure-blob-storage)

2.If you are talking about your own logic for the data error,may some business logic. I'm afraid that ADF can't detect that for you, though it's also a common requirement I think. However,you could follow this case ([How to control data failures in Azure Data Factory Pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535339/how-to-control-data-failures-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines)) to do a workaround. The main idea is using custom activity to divert the bad rows before the execution of copy activity. In custom activity, you could upload the bad rows into Azure Blob Storage with .net SDK as you want.

---

***Update:***

Since you want to log all incompatible rows and enforce the job failed at the same time, I'm afraid that it can not be implemented in the copy activity directly.

However, I came up with an idea that you could use If Condition activity after Copy Activity to judge if the output contains `rowsSkipped`. If so, output False,then you will know there are some skip data so that you could check them in the blob storage.

[image]

Comment: I've read Fault tolerance. But the problem is I need to abort the job after logging the incompatible rows. Does Fault tolerance support this situation? Or I have to raise an error on purpose?

Comment: @Jeff_hu Abort activity on first bad row doesn't meet your requirement?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because I have to log all incompatible rows, too

Comment: The Pipeline is still "succeed", isnt it?  I think I have to raise an error on purpose. But thanks. I will mark your answer.